# Run exiftool across all file types

Tags: exiftool

I am using exiftool to recursively search across directories containing hundreds of files. At present, it is returning the results to a .csv file. Manually comparing my results, there are some files within the target directory that do not have a valid file extension. Nonetheless, when examining the raw data (or adding .jpeg as the extension), the files are indeed image files.

Is there any way to force exiftool to process all files regardless of what the file extension is or indeed whether it has a file extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the [`-ext` option](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#ee).

Add `-ext "*"` to your command to process all files.